# Error when running MySQL query, looking for right syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I get the following error when running my .php file:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''feeds_list' SET 'cron' = now() WHERE 'feed_id' = '1'' at line 1

Here is the code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE 'feeds_list' SET 'cron' = now() WHERE 'feed_id' = '$feed_id'") or die (mysql_error());
```

Thanks for helping me out

Comment: Try this one

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE 'feeds_list' SET `cron` = now() WHERE `feed_id` = '$feed_id'") or die (mysql_error());

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `''` around table names and column names, it should be:

```
UPDATE feeds_list SET cron = now() WHERE feed_id = '$feed_id'
```

or use a backticks (``).

Comment: or change to backticks (``)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. The tutorial I followed used backticks, but I assumed regular ticks would work the same way. Thumbs up :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE feeds_list SET cron = now() WHERE feed_id = '$feed_id'") or die (mysql_error());
```

USE cron Not 'cron'

Answer (score 0):

if you are putting single quotes on the field name it will show error, don't get confused in single quotes and backticks they are completely different.